# Plesk ignores .htaccess file

Tags: .htaccess, iis, url-rewriting, plesk

I am very new to URL re-writting and I am using Plesk which is **Windows based** web server and hence I cant use Apache's mod_Rewrite.. can anyone tell me steps for this to happen?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try [ISAPI Rewrite](http://www.helicontech.com/isapi_rewrite/) for IIS. It supports mod_rewrite rules of Apache and it is supported by Plesk.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe too late for OP but it might be useful for anyone coming across this. If [URL Rewrite](http://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/url-rewrite) is installed in IIS then you can follow [this guide](http://www.iis.net/learn/application-frameworks/install-and-configure-php-applications-on-iis/translate-htaccess-content-to-iis-webconfig) to translate htaccess into web.config.

It worked with my case, running PHP website in a shared hosting with Plesk and IIS under ISAPI